# Buzzer Voltage and Current waveforms

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, speakers, piezo-buzzer

I have a buzzer circuit.

[image]

Waveform :

[image]

My questions :

1. I have marked the points in the circuit where I am measuring the voltage and the current. PWM pulse is given to the base of the transistor. 
   I want to understand why the voltage waveform is like that and the current waveform is like that?
   Why is the voltage waveform Flat and the current waveform like spiked?
2. I would like to understand, only what will happen if I keep increasing the PWM pulse width at the base of the transistor. Please help me understand. (I don't write codes which is why I would not be able to check this by varying the PWM output coming from the Microcontroller to the base of the transistor)

Comment: The voltage is being measured at the power source which is a low impedance and will therefore remain (within some small amount) at 12V. I would expect it to be varying on the other side of the buzzer.

Comment: You measure a flat voltage waveform since you measure at the supply, which is supposed to be flat. What Peter Smith says, I got ninja'd

Comment: Please help me to understand why the current waveform is like this

Comment: @Newbie - Hi, you said: "*Please help me to understand why the current waveform is like this*" (a) Are you asking why it pulses at approximately 1.45 Hz? Or are you asking why there are higher frequency current spikes during the "On period" of 690 ms? Or something else? (b) Please link to the datasheet for the actual "buzzer" marked LS800 on the schematic. (c) Why does the start of the current waveform seem to have been edited (it's white, when it should be blue)? (d) Why did you *not* measure (and give us) the waveform at the PWM signal (base of the transistor)? Thanks.